# iPhone Bluetooth connection (2 questions)

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I have two questions:

1. I want to trasfer data between iPhone and another Bluetooth device. It may be iPhone, iPod  touch or any other mobile, like Nokia, Samsung or any PC. Is it possible in iPhone programming? If yes, please give me guidelines.
2. Can we test Bluetooth applications in iPhone simulator?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165288/is-file-transfer-possible-to-iphone-3-0-via-bluetooth-or-not .  See also these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427250/how-to-use-bluetooth-to-connect-two-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth

Comment: Also, you appear to have just asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107526/iphone-blue-tooth-connection

Answer (score 1):

No we can't test bluetooth in simulator. for testing we need minimum ios 3.0 version

Answer (score 0):

[**iPhone Bluetooth Does Nothing But Calls**](http://gizmodo.com/274068/iphone-bluetooth-does-nothing-but-calls)